# Don't show Title FlyoutItem Shell in Drawer - xamarin forms

Tags: shell, xamarin.forms

I want to have a **Tab Bar** and a **Drawer** in the form

In this form I use **Shell**

I do not intend to display any **Tabbar** items in Drawer
now

I created the **Tabbar** at the bottom of the page once with the following code:

```
<TabBar Title="Tab bar FlyoutItem"  FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem"  >
    <Tab Title="T1" Icon="T1.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views: page1}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T2" Icon="T2.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views: page2}"/>
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="T3" Icon="T3.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views: page3}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T4" Icon="T4.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views: page4}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T5" Icon="Home.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views: page5}"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Output :
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8MjB.jpg)

And once again I used **Flyout** instead of **tabbar** (code below):

```
< FlyoutItem Title=”Tab bar FlyoutItem”  FlyoutDisplayOptions=”AsSingleItem”  >
    <Tab Title=”T1” Icon=”T1.png” >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate=”{DataTemplate views: page1}” />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title=”T2” Icon=”T2.png” >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate=”{DataTemplate views: page2}”/>
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title=”T3” Icon=”T3.png” >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate=”{DataTemplate views: page3}”/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title=”T4” Icon=”T4.png” >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate=”{DataTemplate views: page4}”/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title=”T5” Icon=”Home.png” >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate=”{DataTemplate views: page5}”/>
    </Tab>
</ FlyoutItem >
```

OUTPUT :
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxVny.jpg)

I created the **Drawer** using the following code :

```
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">

    <Tab Title="T6" Icon="email.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:page6}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T7" Icon="email.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:page7}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T8" Icon="email.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:page8}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T9" Icon="email.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:page9}"/>
    </Tab>
    
</FlyoutItem>
```

This time **Drawer** is displayed but its **Title Of Tabbar** is also displayed in **Drawer** as shown in the figure.

OUTPUT :
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vYEv.jpg)

Please help me how I can not display the Title in Drawer.

Thank

Comment: Are those 3 portions of code are combined in one or independent? could you possibly show them combined as a final what you are using? Have you tried deleting `Title=”Tab bar FlyoutItem”`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'M find

The

> Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"

must be added to the TabBar

I share the code below :

```
<TabBar Title="Tab bar FlyoutItem"  Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem"  >
    <Tab Title="T1" Icon="T1.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:T1}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T2" Icon="T2.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:T2}"/>
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="T3" Icon="T3.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:T3}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T4" Icon="T4.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:T4}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T5" Icon="Home.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}"/>
    </Tab>

</TabBar>

<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True">

    <Tab Title="T6" Icon="email.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:T6}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T7" Icon="email.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:T7}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T8" Icon="email.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:T8}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="T9" Icon="email.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:T9}"/>
    </Tab>

</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Can you please accept this answer (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).